# How do I define my endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord, rails-activerecord, restful-architecture

In my API I want an endpoint to provide a subject account's ID and have it return other account records associated with the subject. My models are as follows:

This is my main account model. Both subjects and associates are of type account:

```
class TabAccount < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :subjects, through: :subject_tab_account_relationships, source: :subject
  has_many :subject_tab_account_relationships, foreign_key: :id_associate, class_name: "TabAccount"

  has_many :associates, through: :associate_tab_account_relationships, source: :associate
  has_many :associate_tab_account_relationships, foreign_key: :id_subject, class_name: "TabAccount"
end
```

This is my account relationship model. This provides the many-to-many self-join relationships between subjects and associates:

```
class TabAccountRelation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ref_relationship_type

  belongs_to :subject, foreign_key: "id_subject", class_name: "TabAccount"
  belongs_to :associate, foreign_key: "id_associate", class_name: "TabAccount"
end
```

I know that works because I'm able to use the model inside my Rails code but I'm not entirely sure how to expose this relationship through an endpoint. I know in the routes map file you're supposed to add child resources to a parent resource, but I'm not sure what's the child in this case. This is what I have so far for my route mapping:

```
resources :tab_accounts do
  resources :associates
end
```

And here's my account controller:

```
# GET /tab_accounts/:id_subject/associates
# GET /tab_accounts/:id_subject/associates.json
def index
  if params[:id_subject]
    _limit = if params[:limit].present? then params[:limit] else 100 end
    @tab_accounts = TabAccount.find(params[:id_subject]).associates.limit(_limit)
  else
    @tab_accounts = TabAccount.offset(params[:offset]).limit(_limit)
  end
end
```

And here's my output to stderr:

```
Started GET "/tab_accounts/2646/associates.json?limit=5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-21 22:51:54 -0400
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant AssociatesController):
```

Has anyone ever exposed aliases/sources through endpoints before? How did you do it? Am I close to getting it right?

Comment: You should add your `AssociatesController` to your question since it is the subject of your error.

Comment: Did you define `AssociatesController` ? That controller should be responsible for all logic on specific endpoint as it's nested on `tab_accounts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding nested resources you can add additional routes to your existing resource. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions.

So instead of using this:

```
resources :tab_accounts do
  resources :associates
end
```

you can switch to this:

```
resources :tab_accounts do
  member do
    get :associates
  end
end
```

You would then add the corresponding `associates` action to your existing Accounts controller.

Comment: Getting closer... Now I'm getting this error: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) :associate in model TabAccount. Try 'has_many :associates, :through => :associate_tab_account_relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ref_platform, subjects, subject_tab_account_relationships, associates, associate_tab_account_relationships, tab_community_accounts, tab_communities, tab_client_project_accounts, or tab_projects?):`.

Comment: I updated my accounts model to say `source: :associates` (simply making "associate" plural) and I got the following:  `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError (Cannot have a has_many :through association 'TabAccount#associates' which goes through 'TabAccount#associate_tab_account_relationships' before the through association is defined.):`